# IOS 8 crash wen using image at a custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using a custom UITableViewCell , which I did with the help of a xib file , when I put an Image in my xib file my app crashes , this is the cellForRowAtIndexPath method (the first few lines where the app crashes):

```
    var cell : RecipeTableViewCell? = self.tableView?.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("RecipeCell") as? RecipeTableViewCell

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        self.tableView?.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "RecipeCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "RecipeCell")
        cell = self.tableView?.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("RecipeCell") as? RecipeTableViewCell
    }
```

it crashes at this line :

```
self.tableView?.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("RecipeCell") as? RecipeTableViewCell
```

and I get this message :
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView _isResizable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.

I know that there's no such method (isResizable) for UIImageView it's for UIImage , so what's the problem ???

Answer (score 0):

This error usually happens when you are using **UIImageView** in place of **UIImage**.For example, if you are using image views instead of images in some animations, Check in your RecipeTableViewCell class and change the UIImageViews to UIImages.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by removing the xib file and recreate it , it was due to unclean xib file , thank you all :D

Comment: I had the same problem. I could not see what was wrong in my Storyboard. Until I finally got it: I had tried to use "image" as a name for the image in my table view cell - which is forbidden - before renaming it by "icon". But I did not removed the link in Referencing Outlets. That was the cause of my crash.

Comment: Thanks, you just saved me a massive headache!

Answer (score 0):

For me it was because of briefly setting `@IBOutlet` for `UIImageView` from my xib, and then removing outlet from the Swift file only (so .xib still "thought" it was connected to some code, but it wasn't).